# Error while running a spring application( org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: URL format error)

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, h2

I am trying to use h2 embedded persistent database.

And get the following error on running the application-

```
    2020-03-17 21:12:59.811  INFO 6204 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2020-03-17 21:13:00.868 ERROR 6204 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: URL format error; must be "jdbc:h2:{ {.|mem:}[name] | [file:]fileName | {tcp|ssl}:[//]server[:port][,server2[:port]]/name }[;key=value...]" but is "jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample" [90046-200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:622) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
        at ...
```

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample;SET CACHE_SIZE 8192;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.datasource.username=sa

spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Comment: your error shows that the URL given is `jdbc:h2:/data/sample` instead of `jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample`

Comment: i have improved the question and i am still getting the same issue when i use 'jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample'

Comment: Seems like your new url now has double colons (::)

Comment: fixed that too. Still getting the same error. am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using the following in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:${user.dir}/data/sample;CACHE_SIZE=8192;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `SET CACHE SIZE 8192;` with `CACHE_SIZE=8192;`.

```
jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample;CACHE_SIZE=8192;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
```

Comment: in this case i am getting the following error - The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MVStore background writer nio:C:/data/sample.mv.db] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

Comment: This problem is not related with your question in any way. If you use an embedded database in the web application with H2 in the classpath of your application, you need to add an implementation of `ServletContextListener` with `@WebListener` annotation and in its `contextDestroyed()` method execute the `SHUTDOWN` command in the database using the JDBC directly (`DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password).createStatement().execute("SHUTDOWN")`) or somehow through Hibernate.